# How many groups are there in this regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I have below code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "This order was placed by Mr.Dufresne! OK?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=by)(\\s+)(.*?)(\\s+)(?=OK)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("group 0: " + matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

The above snippet produces the following output:

```
group 0:  Mr.Dufresne!
group 1:  
group 2: Mr.Dufresne!
group 3:
```

Can someone please explain why it is printing `Mr.Dufresne!` for all the matcher groups?

And what does this pattern `(?<=by)` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group 0` is the total string matched by regex (See spaces before and after `Mr.Dufresne!`).

`group 2` is the actual group captured.

`group 1` is `spaces` captured.

`group 3` is also `spaces`

`(?<=by)` is the `positive lookbehind`.Its a `0 width assertion`.It will not consume string.That is why it is not there in `group 0`.Use `by` only and it will appear in `group 0` as now it will be captured too.